# Why does this give Segmentation fault?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

So, I was solving a question which goes like this:

Given a list of n integers, `A={a1,a2,…,an},` and another integer, k representing the expected sum. Select zero or more numbers from A such that the sum of these numbers is as near as possible, but not exceeding, to the expected `sum (k)`.

Note

Each element of `A` can be selected multiple times.
If no element is selected then the sum is `0`.

Input Format

The first line contains T the number of test cases. 
Each test case comprises of two lines. First line contains two integers, `n k,` representing the length of list `A` and expected sum, respectively. Second line consists of n space separated integers, `a1,a2,…,an,` representing the elements of list `A`.

Constraints:

```
1 ≤ T ≤ 10 
1 ≤ n ≤ 2000 
1 ≤ k ≤ 2000 
1 ≤ ai ≤ 2000, where i∈[1,n]
```

Output Format

Output `T` lines, the maximum sum for each test case which is as near as possible, but not exceeding, to the expected sum `(k)`.

Here is the problem link: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/unbounded-knapsack

Now, I developed a top-down approach for this as follows:

```
 int knapsack(int arr[],int n, int Sum, int dp[][1000])
{
    if ( n < 0 || Sum < 0 )
        return 0;
    if(n==0||Sum==0)
    {
        dp[Sum][n] = 0;
        return 0;
    }
    if (arr[n-1] == Sum)
    {
        dp[Sum][n-1] = arr[n-1];
        return arr[n-1];
    }

    else if (dp[Sum][n] != -1)
        return dp[Sum][n];

    else if(arr[n-1] > Sum)
    {
        dp[Sum][n] = knapsack(arr,n-1,Sum,dp);
        return dp[Sum][n];
    }
    else //gets selected or doesn't get selected
    {
            dp[Sum][n] = max( arr[n-1] + knapsack(arr,n,(Sum-arr[n-1]),dp) , knapsack(arr,n-1,Sum,dp) );
            return dp[Sum][n];
    }
}
```

However, the above gives a Seg fault when the input is given as:

```
1
5 9
3 4 4 4 8
```

I tried debugging it but it shows a Seg-fault at the beginning of the function after many recursive calls. Am I missing out any condition?

Comment: Check array bounds. Are `dp` and `arr` big enough?

Comment: why not post your segfault to http://ideone.com/

Comment: They are, atleast for the test case that I have mentioned, they are.

Comment: http://ideone.com/6P5XwE This is the ideone link

Comment: With full code I could be sure, but from your description, it sounds like a stack overflow from too much recursion.  If that much recursion was intended, then the ways of making the stack big enough are OS specific.  Is this on Windows or Linux or what?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with an [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: @JSF, check the full code on the ideone link.

Comment: Since you're asking about a segmentation fault, you're really after implementation details, not the underlying algorithm. We should lose the `algorithm` tag.

Comment: If you feel their can be a better algorithm, feel free to include it here. :)

Comment: Your program crashes because you feed it a bunch of garbage values in the `arr` array. The sums will easily exceed the size of your `dp` array and, obviously, cause the crash. JSF's answer below correctly points out the error. This is another reason to declare variables *as locally as possible*. A stray `i` variable, which lived longer than it should have. prevented the compiler from catching this bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `else`:

```
dp[Sum][n] = max( arr[n-1] + knapsack(arr,n,(Sum-arr[n-1]),dp) , knapsack(arr,n-1,Sum,dp) );
```

It should be `n - 1` as well, because you're done with the current element no matter what. Like it is now, it will do more recursive calls than necessary. With this fix, the segfault is gone on my PC and the function returns `0`.

```
dp[Sum][n] = max( arr[n-1] + knapsack(arr,n-1,(Sum-arr[n-1]),dp) , knapsack(arr,n-1,Sum,dp) );
```

This program correctly returns `8` as the answer for your example:

```
int knapsack(int arr[],int n, int Sum, int dp[][1000]);



int main()
{
    int t;
    int n,k;
    cin>>t;
    int i,j;
    int dp[1000][1000];
    for(int i=0;i<t;i++)
    {
        for ( i = 0; i < 1000; i++ )
            for ( j = 0; j < 1000; j++ )
                dp[i][j] = -1;
        int a[2000];

        cin>>n>>k;

        for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
            cin>>a[j]; // you had i here

        while (knapsack(a,n - 1,k,dp) == 0) // lower k until we can build it exactly
            --k;

        cout << k << endl;

    }
    return 0;
}

// knapsack(n, Sum) = true if we can use the first n elements to build Sum exactly
int knapsack(int arr[],int n, int Sum, int dp[][1000])
{
    if (Sum < 0 )
        return 0;
    if(n < 0)
    {
        return Sum == 0;
    }
    else if (dp[Sum][n] != -1)
        return dp[Sum][n];
    else //gets selected or doesn't get selected
    {
        dp[Sum][n] = knapsack(arr,n-1,(Sum-arr[n]),dp) || knapsack(arr,n-1,Sum,dp);
    }

    return dp[Sum][n];
}
```

If you can use the same element more than once, I suggest the following iterative approach with a simple one dimensional array:

```
dp[0] = true
s = 0
for i = 0 to number of elements:
  s += elements[i]
  for j = elements[i] to s:
    dp[j] = dp[j] || dp[j - elements[i]]
```

Where `dp[x] = true if we can build sum x`.

Comment: So, yes, 0 obviously ain't the correct answer. And I do `n-1` because I am not done with that element and I can further use it as well.

Comment: I reached the same conclusion just before seeing your answer, but I don't think you made it clear which n in that line should have been n-1.  It is the one after the first `arr,` on the line you quoted.

Comment: @IVlad, that obviously will not give the correct answer but. Is their something wrong with my recursion?

Comment: @JohnLui I posted a program that gives the correct answer for your example.

Comment: But this is not the right logic for the problem mentioned, because I can select each number any number of times.

Comment: @JohnLui the problem statement doesn't explicitly state that you can use more of the same element. Using `n` instead of `n-1` is not correct there, as it would cause wrong answers due to the other recursive call. I'll add pseudocode for how you can address this problem, with a single dimensional array.

Answer (score 0):

Your other bug is:

```
for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
    cin>>a[i];
```

Notice the i where you meant j